# Как подвинуть блок навигации на уровень главного блока

Tags: html, css

Появилась проблема, что блок навигации надо опустить ниже на уровень главного блока, да так, чтобы они оба начинались по оси y в одной прямой.

Пример того, как должно получится:

[image: Пример результата]

Код блока навигации

```css
ul.nav {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 14em;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-top: 2px dashed #333;
  border-right: 2px dashed #333;
  border-left: 10px solid #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

ul.nav li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">О сервере</a></li>
  <li><a href="rules.html">Правила</a></li>
  <li><a href="donate.html">Донат</a></li>
  <li><a href="staff.html">Администрация</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Код надо видеть. Что за навигация, что за главный блок. Решения у подобных задач может быть не одно.

Comment: Вы добавили код навигации - хорошо, но прочтите ваш вопрос, вам понятно что за `главный блок`, `блок навигации в нужной позиции`? Нам нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `position:relative; top: ...;`, где у `top` ставь расстояние от главного блока до начала страницы (как я понял).
Если же хочешь сделать более надежно, то можешь запихнуть блок навигации и главный блок в один контейнер и уже внутри него поиграть с `position` и `top/left/right/bottom`